# F-test, formulating the restricted regression on R

Tags: r, regression

I'm using R. I have a data file with the following variables:

```
wages = WAGE
years of work experience = EXPER
year of schooling = SCHOOL
a dummy variable for gender = MALE (1= male)
```

I'm trying to do an F-test using the sum of squared residuals method, to test this claim:

a male worker with z years of experience earns the same wage as a female worker with z+7 years of experience, assuming that both workers have equal years of schooling.

My unrestricted regression model is:

```
lm(WAGE ~ MALE+SCHOOL+EXPER, data=wages)
```

But how would I formulate the restricted regression?

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis you want to test is that a male with z years of experience earns the same as a female with z + 7 years.
The way to model this in a regression is to adjust the experience variable for males or females. Since you've created the dummy variable gender or MALE where 1 is assigned to males and 0 to females, you can adjust the experience for males by subtracting 7 from their experience.

So the code for restricted regression would looked like this

```
lmrestricted <- lm(WAGE ~ MALE + SCHOOL + I(EXPER - 7*MALE), data=wages)
```

For more, you can also check this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/fitting-models-in-r-where-coefficients-are-subject-to-linear-restrictions